# How to show selectable text in Popup? Javascript & PHP

Tags: php, yourls

I'm working with a URL shortener script Yourls. Work is going fine after getting some help from you guys. Thank you for that.
Every button is pressed for shorten URL, a popup appear, showing Short URL for that Page. This simple method is fine for Firefox, but I cannot select the text/Shorten URL in Popup in Internet Explorer.
Any suggestions how to show selectable text in popup?

This is the code of the page:

```
<?php 
// Start YOURLS engine
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/load-yourls.php' );

function selfURL() { $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : ""; $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s; $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]); return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; } function strleft($s1, $s2) { return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2)); }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <?php
    // Part to be executed if FORM has been submitted
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['url']) ) {
        $url     = yourls_sanitize_url( $_REQUEST['url'] );
        $return  = yourls_add_new_link( $url );     
        $shorturl = isset( $return['shorturl'] ) ? $return['shorturl'] : '';

        echo <<<RESULT
        "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$shorturl');</script>"
RESULT;

    // Part to be executed when no form has been submitted
    } else {

        $site = YOURLS_SITE;
        $var = selfURL();
        echo <<<HTML
        <form method="post" action="">      
        <p><input type="hidden" name="url" value="$var" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Shorten" /></p>
        </form> 
HTML;
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to edit the code where its saying

```
"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$shorturl');</script>"
```

How can I make the text selectable to copy?

And can any one please tell me why the page http://taimoorsultan.com/y/ is redirecting to another page when we press the button? Is it possible to show the popup on the same page without going to next page? I have already pasted the complete code above.! Thank you!

**This is the Current Code::**

```
<?php 
// Start YOURLS engine
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/load-yourls.php' );

function selfURL() { $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : ""; $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s; $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]); return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; } function strleft($s1, $s2) { return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2)); }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Testing-->
   <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url']): // <-- only include jQuery if url set ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
  <?php endif; ?>
<!--Testing-->
</head>

<body>



<div id="container">
    <?php
    // Part to be executed if FORM has been submitted
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['url']) ) {
        $url     = yourls_sanitize_url( $_REQUEST['url'] );
        $return  = yourls_add_new_link( $url );     
        $shorturl = isset( $return['shorturl'] ) ? $return['shorturl'] : '';

        echo <<<RESULT

RESULT;

    // Part to be executed when no form has been submitted
    } else {

        $site = YOURLS_SITE;
        $var = selfURL();
        echo <<<HTML
        <form method="post" action="">      
        <p><input type="hidden" name="url" value="$var" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Shorten" /></p>
        </form> 
HTML;
    }

    ?>


</div>

<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url']): // <-- only include the div if url set ?>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($shorturl); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking..

Comment: The text which will be shown in the popup, I simple want to make that selectable.

Comment: @Taimoor That is browser-dependent functionality. There's no way to guarantee that it will be selectable. You'll have to make your own alert function.

Comment: Yes, in firefox its selectable but not in Internet Explorer. Any way to show that text in <input></input> ?
Maybe in this way it can be selectable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to change select-ability of the text in Internet Explorer. `alert()`'s are very basic ways of displaying a message and there are no configurable options, other than the message.

If you want more control you'll have to display the message on the page instead, or create your own dialog or use something like the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

For example on the page instead:

```
echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($shorturl) . '</p>';
```

Or in an `<input>`:

```
 echo '<input type="text" value="' . htmlspecialchars($shorturl) . '" />';
```

To add a jQuery Dialog to your page, your `<head>` section would need to look like (using the jQuery CDN):

```
<head>
  <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): // <-- only include jQuery if url set ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
  <?php endif; ?>
</head>
```

Add the `div` that will become the dialog to within your `<body>` element:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): // <-- only include the div if url set ?>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($shorturl); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain and help in using jQuery UI Dialog for above code?

Comment: @Taimoor see my edit - added an example of a jQuery UI Dialog.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes its working! But a little problem, the dialog box is also appearing on the first page when I load the website. How to disable it? have a look http://taimoorsultan.com/y

Comment: You can add a condition to the jQuery part - I have added an `if` statement around the div and the jquery includes.

Comment: Dreamweaver is showing error in the first and last line, and also seeing error when uploaded file.
I think there is also a problem?
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($shorturl);</p>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' 
This is the error on this line:
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url']): // <-- only include jQuery if url set ?>

Comment: Still getting errors. I guess I'm doing some thing wrong. I have added the current code in the question, and here is the output of that code http://taimoorsultan.com/y
Please have a look!

Comment: There was a missing `)` around the if statements. Have a look now.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to display Popup on the same page? I mean currently popup shows at the next page which is blank.

Comment: What do you mean by display it on the same page? It's already on the same page isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but when the popup appears, the button of shortening link disappear. And when I close the dialog box, the it just show a blank page.

Comment: You would need to move the form out of the `else` so that it always shows.

Comment: Means I can delete the else?

Comment: Yes because you want to show the form always, instead of before when it only shows if the form wasn't submitted.

Comment: Yeaa! Done. :D Thanks a lot MrCode.. Wish you success and happiness in your future :D Thanks

Comment: No problem, same to you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is different behavior from browser to browser. You can not do this with `alert`. Instead use a custom dialog window. You could use the [jQuery UI Dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) or the [Twitter Bootstrap Modal plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: Can you please explain a bit How can I use jQuery UI Dialog plugin with above code I have given?